# How can I add a draggable Polygon function in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, drawing, paint

I have been trying to add a draggable polygon. The process is that *User gives me length of 4 sides and then a shape is generated which is placed on canvas. He should be able to drag the points of polygon*. In flutter, free hand drawing app can be created using `GestureDetector`, paint widget. But i was not able to find proper option to create simple draggable line or polygon.

Comment: post your `CustomPainter`'s code then

Comment: there's no "simple draggable line" in custom paint, you just get the coordinates using GestureDetector like you said, and do the math yourself